# Watchkit passcode button press detection

Tags: watchkit

In the apple watch's passcode setting screen the passcode on top updates as soon as a user clicks on the buttons and not after lifting the finger. How can one achieve that in Xcode 6.3? Because the only event that triggers the ibaction is the touch up event

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that behavior is possible with the current version of WatchKit. Apple is likely using their own internal method to accomplish that (as they do with many/most of the default Watch apps). Hopefully we'll get more functionality in the next major update.